# Deleting a row from MySQL database using Node JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodes, nunjucks

I'm having trouble deleting row(s) from an HTML-rendered MySQL table using Node JS and Nunjucks.  Basically, I want to be able to delete a row from a table but my delete button does not work. Any ideas on what I should try?

HTML/Nunjucks Code:

```
 <tr> {% for results in awards %}
            <td>{{ results.awardtype }}</td>
            <td>{{ results.awardeename }}</td>
            <td>{{ results.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ results.awardtime }}</td>
            <td>{{ results.awardate }}</td>
            <td>{{ results.comments }}</td>
            <form action="/Delete_Award" method="post">
            <td align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>
</tr> {% endfor %}
```

JS:

```
app.post('/Delete_Award', function(request, response) {
        var connection = request.app.get('pool');
        if (request.session.loggedin) {
            connection.query('DELETE FROM awards WHERE awardeename = ?', [request.body.awardeename], function(error, results, fields) {
                if (error) {
                    throw error;
                } else {
                    response.render('Delete_Award.html', { msg: 'Successfully deleted!' });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

https://pasteboard.co/IG55dUp.png

Comment: You do not send any parameters back when you click the delete button...

Comment: Looks like you should add a hidden input with awardeename as the name of the field and has the awardeename as the value. That should get the value in request.body for you.